# Elasticsearch - Autocomplete with corrections

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is a sample context :

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/testso -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "person": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testso/person/1' -d '{
  "name" : "foo bar",
  "context_id" : 1
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testso/person/2' -d '{
  "name" : "fou bar",
  "context_id" : 1
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testso/person/3' -d '{
  "name" : "foo baz",
  "context_id" : 2
}'
```

I'm looking about a method to help user to "correct" its writing and autocomplete it, in a specific context.

Exemples, looking for context 1 :

```
"foo bar" => [ "foo bar", "fou bar" ]
"fou bar" => [ "foo bar", "fou bar" ]
"foo"     => [ "foo", "fou", "foo bar", "fou bar" ]
"fol"     => [ "foo", "fou", "foo bar", "fou bar" ]
```

I have tested some elasticsearch functionnalities... `suggest` does not take account of `"query"` option :

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/testso/person/_search?search_type=count -d '{
  "query" : { "query_string": { "query": "context_id:2" } },
  "suggest": {
    "text" : "foo baz",
    "my_suggestion": {
      "term" : {
        "field" : "name"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

... returns suggestions "foo bar" and "fou bar", which belongs to context 1.

Do you have any idea about how query elasticsearch to return things like this ? A specific mapping ? An other functionnality ? A specific indexer ?

Answer (score 0):

The query option is not taken into account, as Elasticsearch uses [FST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer) to enable the prefix completion functionality. It's a very fast in memory datastructure and enables suggestions within 1 ms. If you would add query or filter options, you would slow done the suggestions process.

Regarding your use case: They anounce the [context suggester](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html) in their API documentation with the 1.2.0 release, which should serve your needs.

In the meantime, you can implement some walkarounds:

- Create a separate index for the suggestions of every contextId
- Add the context information to the suggestion field and also to the query:
  The mapping

  ```
  PUT /testo/person/_mapping{
  "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "name_suggestion": {
        "type": "completion"
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  Define the possible suggestions hits and the output

  ```
  PUT /testo/person/1
  {
    "name": "foo bar",
    "name_suggestion": {
    "input": [
      "onefoo bar",
      "onefoo",
      "onebar"
    ], "output": "foo bar"
    }
  }


  PUT /testo/person/2
  {
    "name": "fou bar",
    "name_suggestion": {
    "input": [
      "onefou bar",
      "onefou",
      "onebar"
     ], "output": "fou bar"
     }
  }

  PUT /testo/person/3
  {
    "name": "foo baz",
    "name_suggestion": {
    "input": [
      "twofou baz",
      "twofou",
      "twobaz"
    ], "output": "foo baz"
    } 
  }

  POST /testo/_suggest
  {
    "suggest": {
      "text": "twofoo",
      "completion": {
        "field": "name_suggestion"
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Note that the completion suggester uses the simple analyzer